How to discard untracked or modified content in any git submodule?
In a git repository, I seem to have untracked or changed content in a submodule
> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
    modified:   mysubmodule(untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

I want to discard the untracked or modified content in any submodule and tried the following commands
git submodule foreach --recursive git reset --hard
git submodule foreach --recursive git checkout -- .
git submodule update --init --recursive
git submodule update --recursive

But none of these did work.
Is there any other command I can try? (I just want to avoid going to any submodule and reset the branch there in case this happens to many submodules at once)...

To remove untracked content you most probably need git clean. Recursive cleaning certainly possible.

Just cd to your submodule and do your git restore or git checkout there

I cannot do it recursively for all submodules at once? Assuming I have 10 submodules with the same issue I have to manually go to each submodule?
